# How to fetch the AWS Route53 hosted zone id?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am newbie to Amazon Services and their API.

Using Amazon route53Clinet class, I know there is a method getHostedZone which get the Hosted Zone information on the basis of ID. But I have a case where I have the domain name and i need to fetch the hosted zone id may be on the basis of the provided domain name? How can i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `listHostedZones` or `listHostedZonesByName` to interrogate the service about your hosted zones.

However... You really need to already know the hosted zone ID -- store or cache it -- because it's possible to create more than one hosted zone in Route 53 for exactly the same domain... and if your code blindly searched for the hosted zone by domain name, you could end up modifying the wrong one... particularly if you fall into the antipattern trap of assuming only one match is possible, and therefore you always select the first match.

Simple deployments will only have one hosted zone for each domain name, but reasons you might have more than one would include private hosted zones (accessible only from inside your VPC) or duplicate public hosted zones, where you are doing a DNS rebuild or hard cutover.  Route 53 allows you to create a second (or third, etc.) hosted zone with 4 different name servers.

Also, of course, it makes sense to have this information locally to avoid making unnecessary API requests, which can cost time and money.  The hosted zone id is, as you likely noticed, also visible in the console.

Comment: public ListHostedZonesByNameResult listZones(String CNAME){
        ListHostedZonesByNameResult zonesResult = new ListHostedZonesByNameResult();
        zonesResult =  route53Client.listHostedZonesByName(new ListHostedZonesByNameRequest().withDNSName(CNAME));
        return zonesResult;
    }        listing hosted zone with using the 'withDNSName()' method didn't return the hosted zone information for the given DNSName. how can i list one specific hosted zone based on DNSName? I understand i couldn't be a good idea but still if i want to?? how can i do that?

Comment: You need to use the domain name at the top of the zone, not one of the source records inside the domain... e.g. `example.com`, not `foo.bar.example.com`.

Answer (score 12):

I use the AWS CLI and pipe the JSON results to the `jq` tool:

```
aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name | 
jq --arg name "example.com." \
-r '.HostedZones | .[] | select(.Name=="\($name)") | .Id'
```

The `jq` expression selects each hosted zone JSON item that contains the name "example.com". Heads up that this may return more than one record.

The output is the matching hosted zone id strings such as:

```
/hostedzone/ABCDEF12345678
```

You can then list resource record sets for a hosted zone id:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
--hosted-zone-id "/hostedzone/ABCDEF12345678"
```

Comment: Instead of `jq`, I would use aws CLIs inbuilt query feature `aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --dns-name example.com --query "HostedZones[].Id" --output text`

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a list with hosted zones ID's.

```
aws route53 list-hosted-zones | jq -r '.HostedZones| .[] | .Id'
```

Comment: Please add description in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be old but I was able to grab the ID with Powershell when initially creating the DNS zone by doing the following:

```
$route53Script = aws route53 create-hosted-zone --delegation-set-id /delegationset/DELIGATIONID --name domain.com --caller-reference blablabla | ConvertFrom-Json
$Route53ID = $route53Script.HostedZone.Id.replace("/hostedzone/","")
```

This gives me the Zone ID that I can then use as a variable to do this:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $Route53ID --change-batch file://C:\default.json
```

I don't know if it's the best way, but it works! I believe you can do almost the same thing in PHP. It's been awhile since I've written some bigger scripts in PHP though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `jq` to search for a zone name.
Simply use `--query` option to aws CLI like so:

```
aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --query "HostedZones[?Name=='example.com.'].Id"  --output text
```