# How to modify the Route53 hosted zone created after domain registration (i.e. method RegisterDomain)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

The AWS suite is very powerful, but the documentation is somewhat frustrating. I'm stuck:

According to the documentation, upon programmatic creation of a domain (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/api-register-domain.html) the response gives you ONLY an OperationID.

However, I already know the ELB I want to then immediately programmatically update the hosted zone that was created (this happens as confirmed at the top of the first referenced document). To do so I need the hosted zone ID that was created. However, their GetHostedZone method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_GetHostedZone.html#API_GetHostedZone_Requests) requires the zone ID, not the domain name.

Listing them doesn't work perfectly either, it's possible to have two hosted zones of the same name. (see [How to fetch the AWS Route53 hosted zone id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544011/how-to-fetch-the-aws-route53-hosted-zone-id) top answer)

Any experience or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Really? That's pretty ridiculous of the Overflow people. Why add an element of confusion when you're asking a question about PROGRAMMING a SERVER? Regardless, thanks for the advice, but it's more of a programming question than it is a server question.

Comment: I read your question too quickly and thought it was about administering a server. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Thank YOU for what you do for the community. (top 4%!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found it:
While the following registers the domain and creates a hosted zone of the same name as the domain registered:

```
$client = new \Aws\Route53Domains\Route53DomainsClient([ 'version' => 'latest', 'region'  => 'us-east-1', 'profile' => 'default', ]);
$domainRegistrationResult = $client->registerDomain([
    'DomainName' => '*example.com*',
    ...
]);
```

This code will get the new zone ID. This should work because although there *could* be multiple hosted zones of the same name, unless the domain is unique, it won't register above and never get here:

```
$client = new \Aws\Route53\Route53Client([ 'version' => 'latest', 'region'  => 'us-east-1', 'profile' => 'default', ]);
$showList = $client->listHostedZonesByName(['DNSName'=>'*example.com*',]);
```

You may have to parse the return of $showList[ 'HostedZones' ][0][ 'Id' ] to get the actual ID (it prepends "/hostedzone/")

If you have hosted zones in your AWS account for domain registrations that don't exist, this is risky!

The best way is for AWS to return the ID of the hosted zone on successful registration. But I don't think I can get AWS on the phone. ;)

Comment: You could compare the nameservers listed by the `GetDomainDetail` API and compare them to the nameservers assigned to the hosted zone.  If they don't match, that isn't the right one.  It's not so strange that they don't return the hosted zone id, though... it's created asynchronously... most of registration process is asynchronous, and can fail later.